# Exchangeratesapi.io api add to torann laravel currency package

Tags: laravel, api, package, currency

I am using laravel 7 for show prices with different currencies. Torann laravel currency looks easy but has google finance not working anymore and openexchangerate don't support with free account 'EUR' default currency for update currency rates.  I want to add exchangeratesapi.io to this package.

```
/**
 * Fetch rates from exchangeratesapi
 *
 * @param $defaultCurrency
 */
private function updateFromExchangesRates($defaultCurrency)
{
    $this->info('Updating currency exchange rates from exchangeratesapi.io...');

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $exio = json_decode($client->get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest', ['verify' => 'C:\laragon\etc\ssl\cacert.pem']));

        // Error getting content?
        if (isset($exio->error)) {
            $this->error($exio->description);

            return;
        }

        // Parse timestamp for DB
        $timestamp = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        // Update each rate
        foreach ($exio->rates as $code => $value) {
            $this->currency->getDriver()->update($code, [
                'exchange_rate' => $value,
                'updated_at' => $timestamp,
            ]);
        }

        $this->currency->clearCache();

        $this->info('Update!');

}
```

I tried to like this and give an error

```
Updating currency exchange rates from exchangeratesapi.io...

   ErrorException

  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

  at ...\vendor\torann\currency\src\Console\Update.php:167
    163|         $this->info('Updating currency exchange rates from exchangeratesapi.io...');
    164|
    165|             $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    166|
  > 167|             $exio = json_decode($client->get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest', ['verify' => 'C:\laragon\etc\ssl\cacert.pem']));
    168|
    169|             // Error getting content?
    170|             if (isset($exio->error)) {
    171|                 $this->error($exio->description);

  1   ..\vendor\torann\currency\src\Console\Update.php:167
      json_decode()

  2   ..\vendor\torann\currency\src\Console\Update.php:73
      Torann\Currency\Console\Update::updateFromExchangesRates()
```

What I have to do?

Comment: i would imagine you want to `json_decode` the content/body of the response, not the response object itself

Comment: @lagbox yes its true